# Printf with redefined stdio not formatting correctly using usart

Tags: c, atmega, atmel, usart

I'm working with an Arduino Uno with an Atmega328p microcontroller using an AVR bootloader with Atmel Studio.

I've set up USART communcation and it successfully can send data that is read by a terminal on my computer but the formatting is incorrect when using printf.

```
    /*
 * USART_HelloWorld.c
 *
 * Created: 6/20/2016 4:17:16 PM
 * Author : Kevin
 */ 

#define F_CPU 16000000
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR F_CPU/16/BAUD-1
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int USART_Transmit(char, FILE*);
static FILE mystdout = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(USART_Transmit, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);

USART_Init(unsigned int ubrr){
    UCSR0B |= (1<<TXEN0)|(RXEN0);//enables transmitting and receiving
    UCSR0C |= 3<UCSZ00; //8 bit data, 1 stop bit
    UBRR0H |= (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);  //sets baud rate
    UBRR0L |= (unsigned char)ubrr;//sets baud rate

}
static int USART_Transmit(char data, FILE *stream){
    if(data=='\n') 
        USART_Transmit('\r',stream);
    while(!((UCSR0A)&(1<<UDRE0)));
    UDR0 = data;
    return 0;
}
int main(void)
{
    USART_Init(MYUBRR);
    stdout = &mystdout;
    printf("Server name= 0x%X\nMy name is %s\nThis number is %d!\n", 0xDEADBEEF, "Kevin", 5);
    while (1);
}
```

I'm referencing  [this](http://www.embedds.com/using-standard-io-streams-in-avr-gcc/) when making this.

I should get output like:

```
Server name=0xDEADBEEF
My name is Kevin
This number is 5!
```

But i get:

```
Server name= 0xBEEF
My name is 
This number is 270!
```

Any suggestions

Comment: If the baud rate were wrong you wouldn't get any output, or maybe total garbage. It's not going to screw up just the values that are substituted into the format string.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I'm new to USART.

Comment: Do you get the expected output if the program is writing to a normal terminal or file?

Comment: Yes, I do when I write a tiny test.c file and compile with gcc from my pc.

Comment: Remember that the size of all types in C are platform and system dependent. On a normal PC the `int` type is typically 32 bits, but on smaller embedded systems (like the Atmega328p) the size of `int` is typically 16 bits.

Comment: So try making it a `long int`, with `%lX` format specifier and the `0xDEADBEEFL`.

Comment: ints being 2 bytes may explain why 0xdeadbeef only returns a 2 bytes value but why does "Kevin" not appear at all? Why the number 270?  It seems the data becomes jarbled pretty badly.

Comment: Because putting a `long int` in the arguments where `printf` expects just an `int` makes it process the remaining arguments incorrectly.

Comment: I made it a long int and it does mostly work now, ty.  It now prints out the full 0xDEADBEEF and my name but the output varies now.  Sometimes it will print "This number is 5!" other times " number is 5!"

Comment: The output omits different parts at different times but the first two lines:

server name= 0xDEADBEEF
My name is Kevin

is always correct.  Something wrong with %s?

Answer (score 1):

As Joachim Pileborg and Barmar pointed out, I needed to change the %X to a %lx and change the hex number as a long.  Once this was done the output was mostly correct but some bits of the output would be omitted.

It turns out this is because all transmits of '\n' were converted to '\r' as suggested by the source example.  It turns out in my case this is not what I want.  After I removed:

```
if(data=='\n') 
        USART_Transmit('\r',stream);
```

From the Usart_Transmit function the output was formatted correctly.

Thank you all for the help.